# Find overlapping intervals between two lists

Tags: python, list

Given the two lists below, I want to find all the intervals in `overlap_list` that fall within each of the intervals in the `intervals` list.

```
intervals = [[0, 100000], [100000, 200000]]
overlap_list = [[1000, 41095], [61070, 65414], [86384, 124015], [131226, 150523]]
```

This is my solution:

```
for element in overlap_list:
    start = element[0]
    end = element[1]
    for window in intervals:
        if start > window[0] and end < window[1]:
            print(window, start, end)
```

The problem with this solution is that for each element in the `overlap_list`, I loop over all the windows in the `intervals` list every time the loop runs, while if I am already at a larger position, I would know that I won't find an overlap with the first window. Is there a more efficient way to code this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: the intervals always have shared end points? like [a,b] [b,c] [c,d]? if so I think that something can be done by making it a simple list [a,b,c,d], apply some simple binary search with the heap library I think it is, you know to insert in a list by maintaining the order in a sorted list, and if both end points of the interval you're checking give the same insertion point then you know the interval otherwise there is no match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remember your position:

```
position = 0

for element in overlap_list:
    start = element[0]
    end = element[1]
    for window in intervals[position:]:
        if start > window[0] and end < window[1]:
            print(window, start, end)
        elif end > window[1]:
            position += 1
```